# Can I recall a Stateful Class while in the class

Tags: dart

I am passing the first object of a List myList[] from Class A to a stateful class B that is a separate page in my application. The passed object is therefore created as **immutable** since flutter prefers **immutable classes** and immutable classes need **const constructors**, variables in which **must be final**. In the B class, I later call a function that modifies the object from the List, and objects in a list aren't immutable. But since I have already passed the object, I can't see the updated value. I solved this issue by making: the **value - non-final**, **the constructor - not const**, and therefore **the class - mutable**. Another way I could solve it is to just use global variables instead.

My question is - Is there a way to reinstantiate class B? I.e., go to class A, navigate to page B by passing the (now updated) first object of List myList[] ?

Comment: Please add the code as text, so the problem can be seen with more clarity...

Comment: What code? There is no code.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try using a State manager like [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). From my understanding, you're trying to share variables across different widgets. Using a state management library seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying to do, though, I am wondering if I can do it without a library.

Comment: Please upvote if I answered your question. As you mentioned earlier, your other choice is global variables. Trust me, the library is your best bet. Working with stateful widgets is a pain in the ass. If you use global variables you''ll have to manage the satte fo global variables across different widgets. That's the last thing you want to do in Flutter.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your answer and thank you a ton for your time! Although, I will wait a bit to see if someone suggests a different solution before I accept it as the official answer.

Comment: You can do most of what you want with ValueNotifier and InheritedWidget, but you'll be reinventing a perfectly fine wheel.  Please use the packages.

Comment: Hey @RandalSchwartz lol I saw you int the Facebook Flutter group. Haha great to see sb I know on Stack Overflow